How do i calculate breakeven black scholes volatility for 12 monthly option to hedge a yearly option?
If I own a 1 year call option of 30 black scholes implied vol and i want to hedge it by periodically selling 12 monthly option of same strike, how can i calculate minimum vol needed on monthly option to break even?

Did you mean "selling 12 monthly options of same strike", i.e. to sell 1 option every month each with a maturity of 1 month?

Yes, apologies i should have been clearer.  I means selling 1 month options sequentially 12 times.
